# Installing bsddb3 6.1.1 in Windows: FileNotFoundError: 'db/include\\db.h'

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, bsddb

I'm running Windows 7 x64, with Python 3.4. When I run `pip install bsddb3` I get:

```
λ pip install bsddb3
Collecting bsddb3
  Using cached bsddb3-6.1.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-soqf0_qb\bsddb3\setup.py", line 42, in <module>
        import setup3
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-soqf0_qb\bsddb3\setup3.py", line 375, in <module>
        with open(os.path.join(incdir, 'db.h'), 'r') as f :
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'db/include\\db.h'
----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-soqf0_qb\bsddb3
```

So I tried [downloading the sources for bsddb3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bsddb3/6.1.0). I made sure I had the BSD DB Windows binaries from Oracle installed; I downloaded them from [Berkeley DB 6.1.26.msi](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/berkeleydb/downloads/index.html). Moving the `include` and `lib` directories from the DB install to a /db directory in the bsddb3 folder fixed the problem of not being able to find the libraries. But then the setup failed on a missing variable that's in the posix section but not properly declared in the Windows section.

Fixing that, and a couple of other adjustments, and `python setup.py build` actually ran the build, but after a bunch of warnings about unsafe conversions it failed with an error:

```
warning: I don't know what to do with 'runtime_library_dirs': ['db/lib']
error: don't know how to set runtime library search path for MSVC++
```

I'm not sure what to do next. Other than rewrite the library I was originally trying to use so that it uses SQLAlchemy instead or something.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One don't really want to spend couple of nights compiling that on Windows, so the best option is to use pre-built binary from [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygraphviz).

Download the package for your Python version (cpXX part of the name) and architecture (win_amd64 or win32), like [bsddb3-6.1.1-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/3kgubn3j/bsddb3-6.1.1-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl), and install it with pip:

```
pip install bsddb3-6.1.1-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl
```

Comment: I tried this but it just gives me an error about a wheel file? "bsddb3-6.2.5-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform." - I'm using Windows 7, python 2.7.13.

Comment: @Adamantus you probably have 32-bit system, pick appropriate package

Comment: Thank you @cyberj0g bsddb3-6.2.6-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl worked for my Python 3.6 and 64 bit Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Based on cyberj0g's answer.
https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#bsddb3

```
pip install bsddb3-6.1.1-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl
```

Note: the cp part is corresponding to the CPython version.

which means cp36 is for CPython 3.6.And divided into 32-bit and 64-bit versions for windows

- bsddb3‑6.2.5‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl
- bsddb3‑6.2.5‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl