# PIP wheel error thrown for Python 3.9.7, when installing BerekelyDB 18.1.8 (Cmd Prompt)

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-wheel

```
Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [19 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\honne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\honne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "C:\Users\honne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "C:\Users\honne\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-apinb4aw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 325, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
        File "C:\Users\honne\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-apinb4aw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\honne\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-apinb4aw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 480, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend, self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\honne\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-apinb4aw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 81, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\honne\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n9ba85rp\berkeleydb_ae21063b3b334b2aaa145da3de8a64d7\setup3.py", line 346, in <module>
          with open(os.path.join(incdir, 'db.h'), 'r') as f :
      FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'db/include\\db.h'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.
```

I've tried multiple things, a fresh reinstall of PIP, reinstalling Wheel, updating pip, trying to run with the --no-binary, --no-binary=:all and attempting to install bsddb3 (even though I was on Python version 3.9.7.

Any ideas? I think I might have to downgrade Python to 3.6? Or higher.
Haven't messed with Python in a while, not sure the cause. It'll download, but fails attempting to build wheel.

Comment: What command did you use to install?

Comment: Also can you show the complete error message from the word *Traceback*? There could be some useful information there

Comment: @journpy
The command I used to install was "pip install (smth)"
Here is the beginning of the error message:
Collecting berkeleydb
  Using cached berkeleydb-18.1.8.tar.gz (294 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error

Everything here is all that was given,
I've tried Pip install Berekelydb18.1, pip install Berekelydb, pip install (the one for 3.6 and under)

Comment: Can you try the answers on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33714698/installing-bsddb3-6-1-1-in-windows-filenotfounderror-db-include-db-h and see if it helps you? Similar issues.

Comment: Still throwing more errors, maybe it has something related to the IDE I'm using? (PyCharm)
It's recognizing them as non-existing files.

Comment: I should probably add to this that the script I'm attempting to run requires "BSDDB" to work. Not sure if there's a workout, maybe I should move the versions back.
Also, don't have an Oracle account for whatever reason, don't feel like making one right now though.

Comment: Please have a look at https://pypi.org/project/bsddb3/ and see if it helps. Especially: Warning

This library is deprecated. If you are running Python 3 >= 3.6, please upgrade to berkeleydb library. Check details.

Take note that upgrading to berkeleydb is easy but not transparent. Notably, keys and values are bytes in berkeleydb lib, while in ‘bsddb3’ they are strings. You would only need to change your code to add or remove type encoding/decoding, depending of how you use the library. The process should be simple, nevertheless.

Comment: Hm, I've just tried BerekelyDB, same error.
Tried with multiple other packages, all the same. Libssl, et cetera. It might be a fault with something I have, downgraded to Python2.7.2, doesn't help as there's no quick manual download on PyPi software, as far as I can tell.